# Фиксированный thead с прокруткой tbody

Tags: css3, html, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте! Подскажите как сделать фиксированный `thead` с прокруткой `tbody`, желательно без JavaScript.

Есть метод с применением `display: block;` и указыванием фиксированной ширины к `thead` и `tbody`. При таком подходе, если кол-во элементов не выходит за рамки `DIV`'a, то происходит смещение, на ширину scrollbar'a.

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/caSJC/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 3):

Вот это попробуй. Должно подойти.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
}
section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
td,
th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div {
  border: none;
}

**HTML**
```

```html
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>
            Table attribute name
            <div>Table attribute name</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Value
            <div>Value</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Description
            <div>Description</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the alignment of a table according to surrounding text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>bgcolor</td>
          <td>rgb(x,x,x), #xxxxxx, colorname</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the background color for a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>border</td>
          <td>1,""</td>
          <td>Specifies whether the table cells should have borders or not</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellpadding</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellspacing</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>frame</td>
          <td>void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>rules</td>
          <td>none, groups, rows, cols, all</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>summary</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>width</td>
          <td>pixels, %</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй вот так

```css
table.scroll {
width: 100%;
border-spacing: 0;
border: 2px solid black;
}

table.scroll th,
table.scroll td,
table.scroll tr,
table.scroll thead,
table.scroll tbody { display: block; }

table.scroll thead tr {
width: 97%;
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 16px);
width:    -moz-calc(100% - 16px);
width:         calc(100% - 16px);
}

table.scroll tr:after {
content: ' ';
display: block;
visibility: hidden;
clear: both;
}

table.scroll tbody {
height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

table.scroll tbody td,
table.scroll thead th {
width: 19%;
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid black;
}

thead tr th { 
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
}

tbody { border-top: 2px solid black; }

tbody td:last-child, thead th:last-child {
border-right: none !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="scroll">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Head 1</th>
        <th>Head 2</th>
        <th>Head 3</th>
        <th>Head 4</th>
        <th>Head 5</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
        <td>Content 3</td>
        <td>Content 4</td>
        <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>Content 3</td>
        <td>Content 4</td>
        <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
        <td>Content 3</td>
        <td>Content 4</td>
        <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
        <td>Content 3</td>
        <td>Content 4</td>
        <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
        <td>Content 3</td>
        <td>Content 4</td>
        <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
        <td>Content 3</td>
        <td>Content 4</td>
        <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
        <td>Content 3</td>
        <td>Content 4</td>
        <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите ваш код (или самые существенные его участки) в ответе. Ссылка на внешний ресурс может стать недействительной, и ваш ответ не будет нести пользы будущим участникам.